# how to stub method called in another method in same struct

Tags: unit-testing, go

Code here:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

type Connector struct {}

func (c *Connector) Pool() (interface{}, error) {
  err := c.ping()
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error handle logic");
    return nil, err
  }
  fmt.Println("success logic")
  return 1, nil
}

func (c *Connector) ping() error {
  var err error
  // err = some side-effect RPC operation
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  return nil
}
```

Now, I want to test the `Pool` method of `Connector` struct. Since the `ping` method has some side-effect RPC operation, I need to stub it and its returned value so that I can test each code branch in the `Pool` method.

success test case pseudo-code:

```golang
Stub(c, "ping").Return(nil)
c.Pool()
Expect(fmt.Println).ToBeCalledWith("success logic")
```

failure test case pseudo-code:

```golang
Stub(c, "ping").Return(errors.New("test"))
c.Pool()
Expect(fmt.Println).ToBeCalledWith("error handle logic")
```

Comment: You can't, not a method of a concrete type.

Comment: @mkopriva Can u give me some article/blog about why can't mock/stub a method of a concrete type? Thanks.

Comment: The language doesn't allow this. That is the only reason.

Comment: Instead of stubbing/mocking: Provide a fake for the actual RPC operation endpoint which can succeed or fail. Mocking/stubbing is _vastly_ overrated, especially in Go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to follow [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), it will make the code easier to test.

> Details (concrete implementations) should depend on abstractions.

Refactored code:

`connector.go`:

```golang
package connector

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Pinger interface {
    Ping() error
}

type Connector struct {
    DB Pinger
}

func (c *Connector) Pool() (interface{}, error) {
    err := c.DB.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error handle logic")
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Println("success logic")
    return 1, nil
}
```

Now, create mocked DB which implements the `Pinger` interface using [stretchr/testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) package. Then, pass this mocked DB to `Connector` struct, it's some kind of dependency injection.

Then we can "mock" `Ping` method with different return values.

`connector_test.go`:

```golang
package connector_test

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"

    connector "github.com/mrdulin/golang/src/stackoverflow/62035606"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

type MockedDB struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (db *MockedDB) Ping() error {
    args := db.Called()
    return args.Error(0)
}

func TestConnector_Pool(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("should verifies connection to the database is still alive", func(t *testing.T) {
        testDB := new(MockedDB)
        c := connector.Connector{DB: testDB}
        testDB.On("Ping").Return(nil)
        pool, err := c.Pool()
        require.Nil(t, err, nil)
        require.Equal(t, 1, pool)
    })

    t.Run("should return error if connection to the database is not alive", func(t *testing.T) {
        testDB := new(MockedDB)
        c := connector.Connector{DB: testDB}
        testDB.On("Ping").Return(fmt.Errorf("network"))
        pool, err := c.Pool()
        require.Error(t, err, "network")
        require.Nil(t, pool)
    })
}
```

unit test result:

```sh
=== RUN   TestConnector_Pool
=== RUN   TestConnector_Pool/should_verifies_connection_to_the_database_is_still_alive
success logic
=== RUN   TestConnector_Pool/should_return_error_if_connection_to_the_database_is_not_alive
error handle logic
--- PASS: TestConnector_Pool (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestConnector_Pool/should_verifies_connection_to_the_database_is_still_alive (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestConnector_Pool/should_return_error_if_connection_to_the_database_is_not_alive (0.00s)
PASS
coverage: 100.0% of statements
ok      github.com/mrdulin/golang/src/stackoverflow/62035606    0.364s
```

Coverage report:

[image]